# Instant.Now for NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm trying to get a handle on using the [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) framework by Jon Skeet (and others).

I'm trying to store the current now(Instant).  Instant is created from a long ticks, but what is the current now count of Ticks?

Is it:

```
Instant now = new Instant(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks);
```

And or?

```
Instant now = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
```

Are they equivalent, am I even doing this right?

PS, if Jon answer's this - I'd like to propose an Instant.Now property.

PS2 I know the title contains a tag, but it wouldn't let me have a short "Instant.Now" title.

Comment: `Instant.Now` would be a bad use case for a property because it changes value "behind the scenes" (the BCL suffers from the same problem: `DateTime.Now`). `Instant.GetCurrent()` would be much better, and `new Instant()` might be the best. Disclaimer: I have had zero exposure to Noda Time.

Comment: @Jon There isn't an `Instant.GetCurrent()` - See the [Instant docs.](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_Instant.htm)  There is also only one constructor for Instant, `Instant(Int64)`

Comment: But in any case, the two definitions are equivalent. `Ticks` is an absolute quantity, it doesn't change with the timezone.

Comment: *waits for Jon Skeet to show up, answer 100% accurately, take all the upvotes and leave a happy camper out of ChuckSavage*

Comment: @ChuckSavage: The lack of `Instant.Now` is very deliberate. It's not testable. That's why `IClock` exists.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I did a bit of research and it seems that the NodaTime way is to get the *now* moment according to a [clock](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.IClock.html).

If you want to get the current time using the system clock, just use `SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant()`.

However, instead of using the `SystemClock.Instance` directly in your code, it's preferable that you inject an `IClock` dependency in your time-aware classes.

This will allow you to:

- provide the class with `SystemClock.Instance` at runtime, so the code will use the correct time
- supply a fake implementation of `IClock` during unit testing to allow you to tweak the time as needed in order to test various scenarios (like the passing of time). There's a  NodaTime.Testing project that offers such a class, called `FakeClock`.

I find this very useful. I think having something like `new Instant()` or `Instant.Now` return the current time would make it easier to hardcode usages of `SystemClock` under the covers, therefore missing the testing advantage that NodaTime offers.

For more info on unit testing with NodaTime, see [this link](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/testing.html).

---

Regarding your code examples: they are not equivalent.

- `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime())` will indeed give you the current instant in UTC.
- `new Instant(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks)` will give you a wrong date far in the future, because the BCL's [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) represents the number of ticks since `1/1/0001`, and NodaTime's [`Instant.Ticks`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/P_NodaTime_Instant_Ticks.htm) represents the number of ticks since `1/1/1970` (see the remark [here](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/M_NodaTime_Instant__ctor.htm)).

Comment: I like both answers, but you tell me what I was doing wrong, and why, too - thank you.

Comment: Basically register the clock with the application services as a singleton like this:
`services.AddSingleton<IClock>(SystemClock.Instance);`

Then in your controllers add an IClock injected parameter for anyone wondering how you should go about using `SystemClock.Instance` indirectly.

Comment: As I understand, to inject an instance it needs a public constructor to do so?  I get the error: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type NodaTime.SystemClock'.  Using Autofac:  `containerBuilder.RegisterType<SystemClock>().As<IClock>().SingleInstance();`

Answer (score 18):

[`SystemClock.Now`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/P_NodaTime_SystemClock_Now.htm) returns the current time as an `Instant` value:

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
```

But you may want to heed the remarks in the documentation for the [`IClock`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_IClock.htm) interface:

> **IClock** is intended for use anywhere you need to have access to the current time. Although it's not strictly incorrect to call `SystemClock.Instance.Now` directly, in the same way as you might call [UtcNow](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89w2e3y3), it's strongly discouraged as a matter of style for production code. We recommend providing an instance of **IClock** to anything that needs it, which allows you to write tests using the stub clock in the NodaTime.Testing assembly (or your own implementation).

As a simple example, suppose you have a `Logger` class that needs the current time. Instead of accessing `SystemClock` directly, use an `IClock` instance that's supplied via its constructor:

```
public class Logger
{
    private readonly IClock clock;

    public Logger(IClock clock)
    {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Instant timestamp = this.clock.Now;
        // Now log the message with the timestamp... 
    }
}
```

When you instantiate a `Logger` in your production code, you can give it `SystemClock.Instance`. But in a unit test for the `Logger` class, you can give it a [`FakeClock`](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Testing_FakeClock.htm).

Comment: At the moment I want the current time to plug into the database (aka a timestamp) as a log event timestamp, is IClock overkill?

Comment: It's up to you. If you're not doing any unit testing, then perhaps it is.

Comment: How else would you get the time in *"Production Code"* if not with `SystemClock`?

Comment: In production code, the current time will be supplied by `SystemClock`, but that doesn't mean you actually have to reference `SystemClock` everywhere you need the current time. I've added a simple example to my answer.

Comment: Ok, now I get you.  I couldn't grasp the whole testing concept until you explained that and the link to the `FakeClock` helped clarify it.